# How to get the idToken from Microsoft using react-native-azure-ad-2 in react native?

Tags: react-native, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I am building mobile application in React Native. Where I have to login with Azure AD using React-native-azure-ad-2 package. I have registered my application on Azure AD in App Registration by selecting Public client (mobile & desktop) option.

I am facing below issues:

1) What should I write in Redirect URI while app registration?

2) How do i get the idToken (JWT)? it is giving only access token.

Below is the response which I get from the SDK.

```
{token_type: "Bearer", scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read", expires_in: 3600, ext_expires_in: 3600, access_token: "EwBgA8l6BAAURSN/FHlDW5xN74t6GzbtsBBeBUYAAYc2qpTiRI…1K8vK7jE80AZ6mgzpziYLWeJsFrJHnJ8vJN8nxIerszo5PoQC"}
```

But i need the idToken in JWT format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) What should I write in Redirect URI while app registration?

It does't matter, it is the URI to which Microsoft Azure AD will redirect in response to an OAuth 2.0 request. The value does not need to be a physical endpoint, but must be a valid URI.

[image]

> 2) How do i get the idToken (JWT)?

Add `openid` to the scope.

[image]

Comment: How can I perform sign out operation once user logged in?

Comment: @HimanshuGarg Sorry, I am not familiar with React-native-azure-ad-2 package. You can post a new question.

Comment: @HimanshuGarg I did some research for you and posted the answer there. You can have a look, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will try this.